# SQL solution to this?

Tags: sql, sql-server

**Car Table**(Car_id, Cus_id, Model, Delivery_Date, Reg_No)

```
      101   1   Yaris - Active  05-Jan-2016 aa-168
      102   1   Yaris           06-Jan-2017 ab-168
      103   2   Fortuner        07-Jan-2017 aa-1111
      104   3   Vios            08-Jan-2017 aa-1234
      105   3   Altis           09-Feb-2017 ab-5555
      106   4   Camry           10-Feb-2016 ab-9999
      107   5   Hilux Revo      11-Feb-2017 aa-6666
```

**Service Table**(Car_id, Service_Date, Service_Amount, Service_Detail)

```
      101   05-Feb-2016 2565    1000km
      101   10-Aug-2016 3400    10000km
      101   20-Feb-2016 2100    20000km
      102   06-Feb-2017 2565    1000km
      103   07-May-2017 3400    10000km
      104   08-Feb-2017 2565    1000km
      105   09-May-2017 2565    1000km
      106   10-Mar-2016 2565    1000km
      106   15-Aug-2016 3400    10000km
      106   20-Dec-2016 2100    20000km
```

My goal is to query value from both tables so that it will show

**Intended Table**(Model, Reg_No,Last_Service, Previous_Service)

```
              Yaris-Active aa-168 20-Feb-2016 10-Aug-2016
              Yaris        ab-168 06-Feb-2017 -
              .............................................
              Camry        aa-9999 20-Dec-2016 15-Aug-2016
```

As you can see that the Last_ Service will contain the last date the car uses the service while the Previous_Service will contain the date the car uses the service before it's service. My basic step is to use LEFT JOIN between the car and service table as it is leaned towards the car table.

My intended step is to query Car_id and Count(Car_id) and Group By Car_id as it will indicate the number of existence of that car. After that, use the count number to indicate the last and 2nd last row of that model and designate the value to specified column...However, I have to translate that to SQL....

```
 SELECT Model, Reg_No, Service_Date As Last_Service, Service_Date As Previous_Date
  FROM Car LEFT JOIN Service ON Car.Car_id = Service.Car_id
```

.....................................................................

```
   SELECT Car_id, Count(Car_id) As No.Times
   From Service
   Group BY Car_id
```

I need help...

Comment: You can use LEAD, LAG functions to find out the last service, previous service

Comment: I understood the requirement to be that he only wants one record per car, with current and previous. While it's possible to do this with lag/lead it's fiddly to restrict the number of rows to 1. Easier to use rownumber, that way you can indicate which row you want all data from (and even if you lag, you might end up using row number anyway)

Answer (score 0):

Put this before your first select:

```
WITH countedservices AS(
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY car_id ORDER BY service_date DESC) service_num
  FROM service
)
```

You can now join `countedservices` to the car table *twice* - once with `service_num = 1` and once with  `service_num = 2` to access the current and previous service data respectively

Don't impose these predicates in the WHERE clause if you're using a left join (presumably because some cars won't have been serviced) because it will convert the left join to an inner join. Put them in the ON clause instead:

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
  car c
  LEFT JOIN countedservice cur ON ... AND cur.service_num = 1
  LEFT JOIN countedservice prev ON ... AND prev.service_num = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

use `row_number()` to get the sequence of `service_dates` based on `car_id`, then join the next sequence.

```
select t1.Car_id, t1.Model, t1.Reg_No, t2.Service_Date as Last_Service, t1.Service_Date as Previous_Date
from 
    (select Car_id, Model, Reg_No, row_number() over (partition by Car_id order by s.Service_Date asc) rn, s.Service_Date
        from Car c
        inner join Service s on s.Car_id = s.Car_id) as t1
left join
    (select Car_id, Model, Reg_No, row_number() over (partition by Car_id order by Service_Date asc) rn, s.Service_Date
        from Car c
        inner join Service s on s.Car_id = s.Car_id) as t2 on t2.Car_id = t1.Car_id and t2.rn + 1 = t1.rn
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Like This...

```
 SELECT    Model,
            Reg_No,
            Service_Date
  INTO      #Temp_Output_1
  FROM      Temp_Car        Car
  JOIN      Temp_Service    Servic
    ON  (Car.Car_id =   Servic.Car_id)

  SELECT    Model,
            Reg_No,
            Service_Date,
            (SELECT MAX(Service_Date) FROM #Temp_Output_1 T1 WHERE T1.Reg_No = T2.Reg_No AND T1.Service_Date < T2.Service_Date)  AS Prev_Service_Date
  FROM      #Temp_Output_1 T2
  WHERE     T2.Service_Date =   (
                                    SELECT  MAX(Service_Date)
                                    FROM    #Temp_Output_1 T3
                                    WHERE   T2.Reg_No   =   T3.Reg_No
                                )
```

Comment: your solution is good, but per modal there is only one row and your query returning multiple rows for same model, which is wrong.

Comment: Use Like This.. SELECT Model,
    Reg_No,
    Service_Date,
    (SELECT MAX(Service_Date) FROM #Temp_Output_1 T1 WHERE T1.Reg_No = T2.Reg_No AND T1.Service_Date < T2.Service_Date)  AS Prev_Service_Date
   FROM  #Temp_Output_1 T2
   WHERE  T2.Service_Date = (
          SELECT  MAX(Service_Date)
          FROM #Temp_Output_1 T3
          WHERE   T2.Reg_No = T3.Reg_No
         )